Is there a way to multiply 2 nested lists with elements that have different lengths and then getting their sum?
I have these 2 nested lists wherein in each sublist, the length of its elements have different sizes.
list1 <- list(
  list(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), c(7,8,9)),
  list(c(2,4,6), c(8,10,12), c(14,16,18))
)

list2 <- list(
  list(c(1,0), c(1,2,0), c(1,2,3,0)),
  list(c(1,0), c(1,2,0), c(1,2,3,0))
)

I would like to get the product of these two lists where the length of elements of each sublist follows the length of the sublist of list2. Just like this:
output <- list(
  list(c(1,0), c(4,10,0), c(7,16,27,0)),
  list(c(2,0), c(8,20,0), c(14,32,54,0))
)

then, I want to find the sum of each sublist as a final output:
finaloutput <- list(
  list(c(1), c(14), c(50)),
    list(c(2), c(28), c(100))
  )

I tried to multiply the two lists but it is giving me this error

Error in list1 * list2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Thank you very much for your help!

Hi, if your issue has been resolved, you can accept one of the answers you prefer by clicking the check mark.

A nested Map() solves this.
Map(\(x1, x2) {
  Map(\(y1, y2) {
    sum(y1[seq_len(length(y2))] * y2, na.rm = TRUE)
  }, x1, x2)
}, list1, list2)

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 14

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 50


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 28

[[2]][[3]]
[1] 100


Again, you can use relist like below
relist(
    mapply(
        \(x, y) sum(x[seq_along(y)] * y, na.rm = TRUE),
        unlist(list1, FALSE),
        unlist(list2, FALSE)
    ),
    rapply(list1, length, how = "replace")
)

which gives
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 14

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 50


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 28

[[2]][[3]]
[1] 100


Yes, you can first compute the products and create a list:
list1 <- list(
  list(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6),c(7,8,9)),
  list(c(2,4,6), c(8,10,12),c(14,16,18))
)

list2 <- list(
  list(c(1,0), c(1,2,0),c(1,2,3,0)),
  list(c(1,0), c(1,2,0),c(1,2,3,0))
)

product_list <- list()

for (i in seq_along(list1)) {
  sublist1 <- list1[[i]]
  sublist2 <- list2[[i]]
  product_sublist <- list()
  
  for (j in seq_along(sublist1)) {
    vec1 <- sublist1[[j]]
    vec2 <- sublist2[[j]]
    length_vec2 <- length(vec2)
    if (length(vec1) > length_vec2) {
      vec1 <- vec1[1:length_vec2]
    } else if (length(vec1) < length_vec2) {
      vec2 <- vec2[1:length(vec1)]
    }
    product_vec <- vec1 * vec2
    product_sublist[[j]] <- product_vec
  }
  
  product_list[[i]] <- product_sublist
}

final_output <- list()

for (i in seq_along(product_list)) {
  sublist <- product_list[[i]]
  sum_sublist <- lapply(sublist, function(x) sum(x))
  final_output[[i]] <- sum_sublist
}

print(final_output)

which gives you
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 14

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 50


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 28

[[2]][[3]]
[1] 100


1) eList/zip We can use list comprehensions using the eList package.  First define a mult function that multiplies two vectors with the length handling requirement and then run a nested list comprehension.  To get output rather than finaloutput omit sum.
library(eList)

mult <- function(x, y) {
  length(x) <- length(y)
  replace(x, is.na(x), 0) * y
}

finaloutput2 <- List(
  for(a.b in zip(list1, list2))
    for(c.d in zip(a, b))
      sum(mult(c, d))
)

identical(finaloutput2, finaloutput)
## [1] TRUE

2) eList/indexes A variation is to use indexes.  multi is from (1).
finaloutput3 <- List(
  for(i in seq_along(list1))
    for(j in seq_along(list1[[i]]))
      sum(mult(list1[[i]][[j]], list2[[i]][[j]]))
)

identical(finaloutput3, finaloutput)
## [1] TRUE

3) rrapply The solutions above assume that the inputs are lists of lists of the same shape.  This one only assumes that they are the same shape.  mult is from (1).
library (rrapply)

finaloutput4 <- rrapply(list1, f = \(x, .xpos) sum(mult(x, list2[[.xpos]])))

identical(finaloutput4, finaloutput)
## [1] TRUE

Note
Inputs and expected output taken from question.
list1 <- list(
  list(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), c(7,8,9)),
  list(c(2,4,6), c(8,10,12), c(14,16,18))
)

list2 <- list(
  list(c(1,0), c(1,2,0), c(1,2,3,0)),
  list(c(1,0), c(1,2,0), c(1,2,3,0))
)

output <- list(
  list(c(1,0), c(4,10,0), c(7,16,27,0)),
  list(c(2,0), c(8,20,0), c(14,32,54,0))
)

finaloutput <- list(
  list(c(1), c(14), c(50)),
    list(c(2), c(28), c(100))
  )

Update
Use zip to avoid indexes.  Show the index solution as an alternative.
